# Could not find a way to fill controls inside UserControl C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, devexpress, components

I'm making such a tabbed "Product Version Control", using an UserControl which encloses fields, checkboxes, text areas, grids, and so on. At runtime, when I add a new tab (like we have on browsers), I instantiate a new UserControl (with all components inside). The issue is: I can get all internal component values and fill an object to persist, but not the other way. I can take all values from Object and set them to EditValue (or Text/Value properties) properties of internal components, but they are not showing up to the user.

Consider:

- All my internal components have public set/get methods like shown below

```
    public class TabVersion : UserControl
    {
        ...
        public DevExpress.XtraEditors.SpinEdit seRevision
        {
            get
            {
                return _seRevision;
            }
            set
            {
                _seRevision = value;
            }
        }
        ...
    }
```

- Inside TabVersion class, I have a "fill" method which receives an "Version" object and set all internal components "EditValue" properties like shown below:

```
    public class TabVersion : UserControl
    {
        ...
        public void FillTab(Sheet sheet)
        {
            ...
            this.seRevision.EditValue = sheet.NumRevision;
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

- At runtime, all EditValue component properties are filled but not showing to the user. Do I have to set "Enabled" or "Visible" properties for each component inside my usercontrol?

Any Ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you adding the controls into the UserControl anywhere? If so can you show the code?

Comment: Hi @JaredPar thank you for answering. I created my usercontrol with VS2008 Designer, like a form (positioning, sizing, etc.). The tab creation method you can see [here](http://pastebin.com/Ce2FZ78b) .

Comment: It's hard to help unless we see how these controls are being added into the container control. Need some code or XAML so we can understand how these interact

Comment: Just to share a thought, maybe those "not showing" component values came from runtime generated components, or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @JaredPar I've added a link in my first response, on how do I'm adding this User Control into a new tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... After googling everywhere with no goal, I wrote a "Fill" method that fills all DevExpress controls inside my user control, and called it inside the "Shown" event at the parent form. I think that's a bug from DevExpress, because all Windows default components works all right when I give them their respective values. That's it.